# What is the genre of a movie/character where someone stays low?

Tags: character, genre

Some examples would be

**Spiderman**: Peter Parker works as a Photographer but not even his aunt knows about his other identity until later.

**Mr. Robot (TV Series)**: Elliot/Mr. Robot the one who is the mastermind of most of the hacks but the society(not f) is unaware of it.

**Superman**: He works for The Daily Planet in The Animated Series.

**Black Mirror (Hated in the Nation)**: The hacker is all alone and doesn't reveal in person.

**Batman**: Bruce Wayne but only a few know about his other identity.

**Death Note:** Light Yagami is not known by the World until the end.

Is there a general term for these types of characters or movies?

Comment: **TL;DR;** no. usually characters are not categorized, labled in any way as you asked. also, your question title is pretty much opposite than the last line in your question body, which is *hell'a lot confusing*

Answer (score 5):

### It's called an alter ego

Not a genre, it's called an alter ego (Latin for "other I") means alternate self, which is believed to be distinct from a person's normal or true original personality.

Comment: That's fine but I feel there is a special word for people who don't want to let their secrets out. An Alter ego is a broader term.

Comment: "Secret identity", perhaps

Comment: I would guess this is a very old idea; certainly Jekyll and Hyde is an earlier example but I bet even before that, humans have observed that people behave very differently in different circumstances. Not exactly secret identity but related.

Comment: @AnthonyX That's it. I could filter through the list: https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=secret-identity&sort=user_rating,desc&mode=detail&page=1 while other keywords like disguise also seemed close.